# Convert 3D point to 2D point coordinate system and versa

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, 2d

I am trying to convert point(x,y,z) to point(u,v). I have used The equations in wiki:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-vector#Converting_latitude.2Flongitude_to_n-vector

To transform point (3,2) to 3D

as :

```
 x=Math.cos(lat)*Math.cos(lon);
 y=Math.cos(lat)*Math.sin(lon);
 z=Math.sin(lat);
```

and from 3D point to 2D :

```
v=Math.asin(z);   
u=Math.atan2(y,x);
```

but the problem it does not give the same values that resulting from convert point(3,2) to 3D
Then to 2D again which is not equals to (3,2)

Comment: `x=Math.cos(x)*Math.cos(y); y=Math.cos(x)*Math.sin(y);`  I assume this isn't the actual code?  Otherwise you are setting `x`, the angle, to a coordinate-value, then trying to use it like an angle again.

Comment: I am using latitude and longitude as angle which is 3 as latitude and 2 as longitude

Comment: @user1261494: as you have already been told your code is broken.  You have x (and y) on both the lhs and rhs of your first set of equations.

Answer (score 0):

The trig functions you are using expect their inputs in radians, the latitude and longitude you give are measured in degrees.

Comment: I had worked with your note but I did not reach to the exact result